# Get array of objects from array of objects with specific properties using rxjs angular

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have database which is array of objects. It look like this:

```
export const BIKES: Bike[] = [
  {
    id: 1,
    imgUrl:
      'https://cyclingmagazine.ca/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Krypton_A18_2016_red_ultegra_16_1.jpg',
    price: 28000,
    discount: 71,
    main: true,
    shop: 'Canada Bike',
    name: 'Argon 18',`
},
{
    id: 2,
    imgUrl:
      'https://cyclingmagazine.ca/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/etap.shadowpsd_2048x.png',
    price: 7900,
    discount: 41,
    main: false,
    shop: 'Amazon',
    name: 'Aquila Cycles',
}
```

I want to subscribe to array of objects which will consist of 2 properties 'name' and 'shop' and theirs values.

Comment: you are asking how to to change the `Bike` interface to take the new array of obejcts?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You want to subscribe to an array of objects with 2 keys? What's that, a new array? And what do you mean "subscribe to an array"? Also, this is your Database (Mongo apparently?) and you're talking about RxJS and Angular, which are in the front-end? I'm lost

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

It can be implemented using `Array.map`

```
const result = BIKES.map(({name, shop}) => ({ name, shop }));
console.log(result);
```

or

```
const result = BIKES.map((item) => {
  return {
    name: item.name,
    shop: item.shop
  };
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: And if you're using a stream from RxJs or elsewhere, there it likely also a `map` method, which should act very similarly.